# T-SQL - How to update these records

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
MyField     Description
-------     -----------
A001        Alcantara
A002        Apacible
            Arctic
            Arkansas

B001        Backdoor
            Ballpen
            Brother
        ..and so on
```

On the records above, how to query (in one query as possible) in T-SQL to update having an output like this:

```
MyField     Description
-------     -----------
A001        Alcantara
A002        Apacible
A003        Arctic
A004        Arkansas

B001        Backdoor
B002        Ballpen
B003        Brother
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for an `INSERT` or an `UPDAATE`?

Comment: Are you trying to UPDATE MyField with the first character of Description and a progressive number starting from the last value of the same type?

Comment: Why do you need this? Unless it is a readonly table then the numbers won't be kept sequential after updates/deletes/inserts. Also are you guaranteed no more than 999 rows per initial letter?

Comment: An UPDATE Darren Davies

Comment: That's right Francesco De Lisi.. Yes, this is no more than 999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
select myfield,description,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by left([Description],1) order by [Description]) as rn
from Table1
)

UPDATE CTE
SET Myfield=left(description,1) +CASE WHEN rn <= 9 then '00' else '0' end+cast(rn as varchar(3)) from CTE
```

Comment: Why `order by (select 0)`? looks like they want alphabetical order.

Comment: First of all, thanks to Anand Phadke for formatting my  question. i don't have any idea how to. ROW_NUMBER is not possible for this. I put 3 records on the MyField for an idea of the output. The first character of the record is base on the first letter of the Description field.

Comment: i did nt get what you are telling here.can you pls explain me

Comment: Very impressive Sir AnandPhadke! You got what i want! Sorry that i just read all your comment late and jsut tested it due to a phone call.. Anyways, thanks so much!

Comment: What do you mean right mark Sir? Sorry but i can't see it here.

Answer (score 0):

It also can be done through a sub-query. Just a alternative way.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET MyField = SortByDesc.ID
FROM
Table1 AS Original
INNER JOIN (SELECT Description,
            LEFT(Description,1)+
            RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Description, 1) ORDER BY [Description])) AS NVARCHAR), 3) AS ID
            FROM Table1) AS SortByDesc ON Original.Description = SortByDesc.Description
```

I tried it on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db079/26/0